# Can I open 2.79b files in 2.8?

Tags: versions, compatibility

I'm now using blender 2.79b. So the problem is, if I change the version from blender 2.79 to blender 2.8, is all of my work in blender 2.79 lost?

Comment: If you are refering to opening 2.8-files in 2.79, then yes, you can't open 2.8-files in 2.79. You have to continue working on them in 2.8. You can try to export individual components through obj / fbx export though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no... 
Yes if you have simple blend files, I saw that 2.8 opens them pretty easily. If you re-save them using 2.8, then, yeah you cannot open them in 2.79. Blender will crash.

No, if you have Armatures blend files (I've been using a simple biped rig from the internet, much like 3DS Max has) then you will have issues. 
Also, I saw that collections tend to disappear from one save to another... (but maybe is because the Armature rig is coming from a 2.7x version...)

Comment: so all of my armature project is dissapear?

Comment: Not the Project. Somehow the project was available (with the animation playing well) In 2.79, I had the bones in a different layer so I opened the same scene in 2.8 (since Cycles is 30% faster there). As far as I understood the layers from 2.79 became Collections in 2.8, so when I first opened the Blender 2.80B I had the bones visible all ok, packed in Collections 1. In Collections 2 I had the body of the character plus the other objects.

Comment: After 2h of animation, I saved and restarted the Mac (so it can update Mac os...) and next time I opened Blender 2.80 (the saved scene) the bones were missing. Collection 1 was empty. (I opened many times Blender, redownloaded, restarted MacOs.) So I redo the animation again and call it a day (it was pretty late in the night). Next morning the Collection 1. (with the bones/Armature) was missing altogether.

Comment: If you are unable to open your file you can always try and use the "append" from the `file` drop down menu to retrieve your data. It seems like that the data bases are still compatible both ways.